# catch return error just like in unix but now in dos/ batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

i am more acustom to unix scripting.

`findstr "ORA-[0-9]" alert_%%A.log>>%output-file%`

in unix i can catch the return error:

`if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then 
    echo "there is no ORA-ERROR found on alert log" > $ERRLOG`

Question:
how can i do that in DOS / batch file?

Answer (score 0):

The `%errorlevel%` variable returns a `errorlevel` if a command fails (with a `.bat` extension, whereas with a `.cmd` extension it changes the `errorlevel` even if a command succeeds).

So, I'm guessing that the above unix command does something around the following of

```
if %errorlevel% neq 0 echo There is no ORA-ERROR found in alert log > %ERRLOG%
```

**Note:**
I'm pretty sure that things proceeded with a dollar sign (`$`) are variables, so I made the file it is outputting it to a variable.

Hope that helps.